# Installed Okular on Ubuntu 22.04 that came with KDE connect,connect indictor, etc

Tags: kde, pdf, 22.04

I just installed Okular using `sudo apt-get install okular`,however, when I when went into the "show application" GUI it shows 4 additional apps, KDE connect, KDE connect indicator, KDE connect setting, KDE connect SMS. Are those 4 KDE applications necessary for Okular to run or can I safely remove them? If I can safely remove them, what are the correct command line to use?

[image]

Kindly advise

Comment: Just remove them. If Okular also disappears (which it won't), reinstall it.